# Регистрация скрипта и возвращение значения

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Мой алгоритм следующий:

1. Нажимает на кнопку в гриде "Удалить строку"
2. Появляется `JS`-сообщение `confirm`(текст) и 2 кнопки: Да, Отмена (стандартные кнопки)
3. Если нажимаем на "Да" - строка удаляется, т.е. выполняется нижеследующий код после выполнения скрипта. Если "Отмена" - то ничего не делаем.

Я так делаю:

```
private void dg_НашГрид_DeleteCommand(object source, System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGridCommandEventArgs e)
{
    //запустить джава-скрипт
    const string  errorMessage = "вопрос подтверждения";

    const string clientScript = "function confirmDelete() {if (confirm(" + "\"" + errorMessage + "\"" + ")) {return true;} else {return false;}}";

    ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "onload", clientScript, true);

    //код удаления...
}
```

Сейчас при выполнении никакого вопроса не возникает (т.к. там функция).  если вы скрипте мы введем `confirm`(текст), то сначала строка удалится и потом появится сообщение, действительно ли вы хотите удалить строку.  **Мне посоветовали результат завернуть в переменную и потом уже в коде ставить условие.**  Я не представляю пока как это можно сделать. Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно логичнее достичь поставленных целей?

Comment: все дело в том, что выполнять этот яваскрипт код нужно **до** того как зайдете в `dg_НашГрид_DeleteCommand`. Добавьте aspx разметку для грида